# Auto populate data into fields using jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I have a passport scanner which scans a document and print out the following format every time it has a new scan. it will just start to write it to any open textarea it sees.

```
START
Surname: SOMETHING
Forenames: NAME
Date of Birth: 10-10-91
Expiry Date:
Issue Date:
Document: PASSPORT
Doc. Number: 150150150
Issuing State: USA
Nationality: USA
Address Street:
Address City:
Address State:
Address Postal Code:
Address Country: USA
Height:
Weight:
Hair Color: BLACK
Eye Color: RED
END
```

The information go into the text field like this:

[image]

I want to prepare fields for this information and when i swipe the passport, so it will fill them all up. I have never expirenced such thing, looking for any ideas how to approach this?

The form can look like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Passport scanner</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="surname">Surname</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="forenames">Forenames</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="forenames" name="forenames" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">

  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could generate the form from your data using a little jQuery, though you probably really need a static form -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var passportArray = $("#scanned").val().trim().split("\n");
  passportArray.shift();
  passportArray.pop();
  for (var i = 0; i < passportArray.length; i++) {
    var line = passportArray[i].split(":");
    var name = line[0].trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
    var $div = $("<div>").attr("class", "control-group");
    $div.append("<label>").attr({
      class: "control-label",
      for: name
    }).text(line[0]);
    var $innerDiv = $("<div>").attr("class", "controls");
    var $input = $("<input>").attr({
      id: name,
      name: name,
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "",
      class: "input-xlarge"
    }).val(line[1].trim());
    $innerDiv.append($input);
    $div.append($innerDiv);
    $("#passport_form fieldset").append($div);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="scanned">
  START 
  Surname: SOMETHING 
  Forenames: NAME 
  Date of Birth: 10-10-91 
  Expiry Date: 
  Issue Date: 
  Document: PASSPORT 
  Doc. Number: 150150150 
  Issuing State: USA 
  Nationality: USA 
  Address Street: 
  Address City: 
  Address State: 
  Address Postal Code: 
  Address Country: USA 
  Height: 
  Weight: 
  Hair Color: BLACK 
  Eye Color: RED 
  END
</textarea>

<form id="passport_form" class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Passport scanner</legend>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, will try that tomorrow. I have added animation example how the info pops into the textfield

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery or just plain javascript to populate the fields like so:

jQuery:

```
$('#surname').val('surnameValue');
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('forenames').value = 'forenamesValue';
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/KdPPBR)